# как сделать чтобы окно показалось после прогрузки всех виджетов? tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
Win=Tk()
#Много всяких виджетов
#Еще очень много всякий виджетов
Win.mainloop()
```

Проблема: Когда запускаю окно на короткий промежуток времени видно как прогружаются виджеты.
**Как сделать чтоб окно показалось только после прогрузки всех виджетов?**

Comment: Попробуйте просто  перед mainloop, написать `Win.update()`

Comment: Этот код никак не демонстрирует проблему.